# Laravel 5: Use simple Pagination arrows with standard Paginate results

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5 offers Paginate and simplePaginate:
http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination

->simplePaginate performs a few less queries and when the pagination is printed out on the page it is just a simple left and right arrow.

I want the simple arrows shown with simplePaginate but I want to use regulare pageinate because it includes the total count of results.

I could manually create these arrows but I was curious if there is a way to use the pager automatically?

Currently using:
`{!! $results->appends(['sort' => $sort])->render() !!}`

Answer (score 0):

You can get total count of page:   `$result->total();`
or count of records each page `$result->count();`